# Where did I go wrong with $\int{\frac{\ln{x}}{x + a}dx}$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, complex-integration

I tried evaluating this integral over the complexes like the following but when comparing to the Wolfram Alpha answer (including graphically), it gets a different answer. I am not sure where I went wrong, but my theory is that is has to do with the multivalued nature of the complex logarithm. I would appreciate some insight. Assume x is complex and a is non-zero real.
$$\begin{align*}
\int{\frac{\ln{x}}{x + a}} dx&= \int{\frac{\ln{(u - a)}}{u}}du
\qquad \small{u = x + a, x = u - a, du = dx}\\
&= \int{\frac{\ln{((-a)(1 -\frac{u}{a}))}}{u}du}\qquad\text{factor our }-a\\
&= \int{\frac{\ln{(1 -\frac{u}{a} ) + \ln(-a)}}{u}}du\qquad \text{properties of }\ln\\
&= \int{\frac{\ln{(1 -\frac{u}{a} )}}{u}}du + \ln(-a)\int{\frac{1}{u}}du\\
&= \int{\frac{\ln{(1 -\frac{u}{a} )}}{u}}du + \ln(-a)\ln(u) + C \qquad\text{set }v=\frac{u}{a}, u=av, dv=\frac{1}{a}du\\
&= \int{\frac{\ln{(1 -v)}}{v}}dv + \ln(-a)\ln(u) + C \\
&= \textrm{-Li}_2(v)  + \ln(-a)\ln(u) + C\qquad\text{with }\mathrm{Li}_2(z)=-\int_0^z\frac{\ln(1-t)}{t}\,dt\\
&= \textrm{-Li}_2\left(\frac{u}{a}\right)  + \ln(-a)\ln(u) + C\qquad\left(v=\frac{u}{a}\right)\\
&= \textrm{-Li}_2\left(\frac{x + a}{a}\right)  + \ln(-a)\ln(x + a) + C\qquad (u=x+a)
\end{align*}$$

Comment: If you ever doubt $\int f(x)dx=g(x)+c$, check whether $g'=f$. Have you differentiated your answer?

Comment: Is $a$ assumed to be negative? If yes, write it.

Comment: @J.G. when I differentiate it, it only reduces to the equivalent if ln(ab) = ln(a) + ln(b) applies, which it supposedly doesn't over the complexes. I'm not sure what step here makes it wrong though and graphing them both gets different graphs.

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan a is assumed to be any real number. If it's negative, it seems to work. If it's not negative, it does not.

Comment: If $a$ is nonnegative, then what does $\ln(-a)$ mean?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Assume a is either negative or positive but also assume x is complex and thus x + a is complex.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is the function $f$ below, and w-alpha gives the [function $g$ below](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral%20log%20x%2F%28x%2Ba%29%20for%20x):
$$
\begin{aligned}
f(x) &= -\operatorname{Li}_2\left(1+ \frac xa\right) 
 + \ln(-a)\ln(x + a) + \text{some constant}\ ,\\
g(x) &= +\operatorname{Li}_2\left(-\frac xa\right) 
 + \ln x \ln\frac {x+a}a + \text{some other constant}\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
Let now $z$ be $z=-x/a$. Then there is a functional equation satisfied by the dilogarithm, connecting $z$ and $(1-z)$, this is $(5)$ on the
[mathworld-wolfram](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Dilogarithm.html) page:
$$
\operatorname{Li}_2 (z) + 
\operatorname{Li}_2 (1-z)
= -\ln z\ln(1-z) +\text{(known constant)}
\ .
$$
Using it,
$$
\begin{aligned}
g(x)-f(x) 
&=
\operatorname{Li}_2(z)
+
\operatorname{Li}_2(1-z)
+
\ln(x+a)(\ln x-\ln (-a))
-\ln x\ln a 
+\text{difference constant}
\\
&=
-\ln\left(-\frac xa\right)
\ln\frac{x+a}a
+
\ln(x+a)\ln\left(-\frac xa\right)
-
\ln x\ln a
+\text{constant}
\\
&=
\ln\left(-\frac xa\right)
\ln a
-
\ln x\ln a
+\text{constant}
\\
&=
\ln\left(-\frac 1a\right)
\ln a
+\text{constant}
\\
&=\text{new constant .}
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: This requires a complex logarithm, I think, as your expressions contain both $\ln(a)$ and $\ln(-a)$.

Comment: If I'm understanding this right, you are demonstrating that they are equivalent expressions up to some constant? If so, then how come the graphs differ (not up to a constant).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Yes, computations are done with function of a complex variable, and the equalities should be understood also after taking care of the monodromy of the involved logarithm and dilogarithm pieces.

Comment: It may depend on the values taken for $a, x$ that the monodromy of the involved functions is inserting a non-constant function. For instance, $\log (-a)$ is not "determined", it is defined up to some multiple of $2\pi i$. And taking "an other multiple" would change the whole expression by this $2\pi i$-multiple times $\log(x+a)$, which is no longer a constant function. We may try to get a "piece of the space" where all involved expressions are real. Or at least the monodromy of the dilog is not touched. For $f$ we need $-a, x+a>0$. But then in $g$ we get the argument $(x+a)/a$ which is $<0$.